# Improving tracking with TrackerCSRT in OpenCV when target goes outside the screen

Tags: python, matching, tracking, opencv

I'm currently using the TrackerCSRT algorithm in OpenCV for object tracking in a video stream. Overall, the algorithm works well when the target is within the screen boundaries. However, I'm facing an issue where the tracker occasionally switches to a wrong target when the desired target goes outside the screen.

Is there any approach or technique that can help improve the tracking performance of TrackerCSRT, specifically in scenarios where the target goes outside the screen? I would like to ensure that the tracking algorithm remains accurate and robust even in such cases.

Any insights, suggestions, or sample code would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!